# what do I need if I wanna put logs into elasticsearch5.0.0(or later version) through flume?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, flume, flume-ng

Here is my system environment:

```
elasticsearch 5.0.0
apache-flume 1.8.0
centos 6.x
```

I put `elasticsearch-5.0.0.jar` and `lucene-core-6.2.0.jar` that I found in `lib` folder of `elasticsearch` into `<flume-HOME>/lib`

And I still get the following error message:

> 18/04/11 16:59:18 WARN lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Component SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@3887d0c7 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } stopped, since it could not besuccessfully started due to missing dependencies

Here is the content I wrote in flume config file:

```
a1.channels = ch1 <br>
a1.sources = r1 <br>
a1.sinks = s1 <br>

... ...

a1.sinks.s1.channel = ch1
a1.sinks.s1.type = elasticsearch
a1.sinks.s1.hostNames = 192.168.1.4:9200
a1.sinks.s1.indexName = flumelog
a1.sinks.s1.indexType = info
a1.sinks.s1.clusterName = mycluster
a1.sinks.s1.batchSize = 500 
a1.sinks.s1.ttl = 3d 
a1.sinks.s1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchDynamicSerializer
```

I know nothing about Java, so it's difficult for me to sort it out. Could somebody tell me what dependencies I need, I searched but can't find any useful information in our countries tech web.